# Zend Framework 2 Tree Route Stack Error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm running into a problem with my child routes in module.config.php. I have it set to where the main route can accept child routes (I've done this before and never have had this issue) but for some reason I am getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\vendor\\zendframework\\zend-mvc\\src\\Router\\Http\\TreeRouteStack.php on line 313
```

I've looked it over and over again but I cannot see what may be causing this. Here is my code for the routing in module.config.php (it only occurs on the /setup page)

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),

            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'       => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),

                        'defaults' => array(

                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'setup' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'setup[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Setup',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'admin-login' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'admin-login[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\AdminLogin',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'member-login' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'member-login[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\MemberLogin',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'logout' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Literal',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'logout',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Logout',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'register' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'register[/:action]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Register',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                'verify' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => 'verify[/:code]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'code' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),

                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Verify',
                            'action'     => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I apologize if this is not enough information but I'm not sure on how to fully describe this. I am on the page that is the home/setup route (setup) but again, am getting the warning about explode().

I don't know if this is relevant but here is my view:

```
<div class="w3-row">
<div class="w3-col w3-container m8 l9">
<?php
    $this->form->setAttribute('action', $this->url(array(
        'home/setup', array('action' => 'index'),
    )));

    $this->form->prepare();


    echo $this->form()->openTag($this->form);
?>

<?php
      $username = $this->form->get('username');

      $password = $this->form->get('password');



      echo $this->formRow($username);

      echo $this->formRow($password);

      echo $this->formElement($this->form->get('csrf_security'));

      echo $this->formElement($this->form->get('submit'));

      echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I had $this->url in the view set up wrong.